# multiple id and name for input and elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form has hundreds inputs and elements for taking exams from users that i have to type an Id and name for every single input

how can i prevent this?
is there a solution by javascript ?

```
<ol>
        <li>
            <div class="qselections">
                <input type="radio" value="1" id="1" name="question1"><label for="1">1</label>
                <input type="radio" value="2" id="2" name="question1"><label for="2">2</label>
                <input type="radio" value="3" id="3" name="question1"><label for="3">3</label>
                <input type="radio" value="4" id="4" name="question1"><label for="4">4</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <br>


        <li>
            <div class="qselections">
                <input type="radio" value="1" id="5" name="question2"><label for="5">1</label>
                <input type="radio" value="2" id="6" name="question2"><label for="6">2</label>
                <input type="radio" value="3" id="7" name="question2"><label for="7">3</label>
                <input type="radio" value="4" id="8" name="question2"><label for="8">4</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <br>


.
.
.
.
.


        <li>
            <div class="qselections">
                <input type="radio" value="1" id="1197" name="question300"><label for="1197">1</label>
                <input type="radio" value="2" id="1198" name="question300"><label for="1198">2</label>
                <input type="radio" value="3" id="1199" name="question300"><label for="1199">3</label>
                <input type="radio" value="4" id="1200" name="question300"><label for="1200">4</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <br>


</ol>
```

Comment: No, you have to type everything by hand, and an ID can't just be a number, in your case it should be at least 50 characters long, and be completely unique for each element ........... or, you could just use a serverside language that generates elements in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for loop to generate the elements dynamically. In that case you don't need to worry about id and name.

Copy this code and paste to index.html file and then open that file in chrome browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Fullscreen backgrounds with centered content">
</head>

<body>

<ol id="questionArea"></ol>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var settings={
        questionCount:5,
        subQuestionCount:4
    };

    var htmlString="";
    var uniqueId = 1;
    for(var i=0;i<settings.questionCount;i++){
        htmlString += "<li><div class='qselections'>";
        for(var j=1;j<=settings.subQuestionCount;j++){
            htmlString +="<input type='radio' value='"+j+"' id='"+ uniqueId +"' name='question"+ i +"'><label for='"+ uniqueId +"'"+">"+j+"</label>";
           uniqueId++;
        }
        htmlString += "</div></li>"
    }

    $(questionArea).html(htmlString);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You again, it is working good but there is a problem , first choice shows 0 (zero) but i want to start from 1 (one).

Comment: in other word we have 4 choice starting from 1 ==> (1 - 2 - 3 - 4) not ( 0 - 1 - 2 - 3 )

Comment: Hi, i have updated the code. Now it will start from 1.

Comment: I'm really sorry to make you in trouble, but a new problem occurred and that's becuase of ununique inputs IDs
could you please make the IDs uniqe
you can see the problem here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vetb20jg/)

Comment: oops, but all of choice will be chosen...
I want one choice to be chosen for every question not all

https://jsfiddle.net/vetb20jg/1/

Comment: now I can just choose one radio button in whole of them :(

one question = just one answer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vetb20jg/3/  :) . Actually i wasn't clear about your requirement. Please don't forget to approve it as correct answer.  Thanks